# How does the diesel engine acclerates the car?

Tags: classical-mechanics

How does the diesel engine acclerates the car? In which direction on the wheel, it exerts the force and how this internal force of a car system acclerates the car?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the diesel engine, fuel is ignited due to a rapid pressurisation by the pistons in the cylinders of a perfect fuel-air mix.
- It ignites, burns and its resulting exhaust gasses expand. **Chemical energy release**.
- This expansion pushes the pistons back.
- Those pistons are connected to the crankshaft. When they are pushes back, the crankshaft is rotated. So, the chemical energy release is converted into **rotational energy** in the crankshaft.
- Through clutch and gearing, this rotating crankshaft is connected to the driving wheels and cause **torque at those wheels**. The gearing takes care of adjusting the torque, so it matches the load/effort needed at the particular speed and acceleration.
- The wheels now carry the rotational energy. And when the wheels touch the asphalt, the torque about the wheel axle is converted into a **linear force onto the road**, which pushes the car forwards.

The directions of the torques at the different parts along the way should be obvious. And the direction of the force at the contact point with the road is of course direction in a way so that it pushes the wheel+car forward.